# data type conversion in dataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have a `csv file` which has a column named population. In this `CSV file` the values of this column are shown as decimal (float) i.e. for e.g. **12345.00**. I have converted whole of this file to `ttl RDF format`, and the population literal is shown as the same i.e. 12345.0 in the ttl file. I want it to show as integer (whole number) i.e. **12345** - Do I need to convert the data type of this column or what to do? Also, I would ask how can I check the data type of a column of a dataFrame in python?
(A beginner in python)- Thanks

Comment: When you read the column you can specify the `dtype` you want with a dictionary in the `pd.read_csv` method: `dtype={'your_col_name': 'int64'}`. However if your data are messy this will fail (maybe missing data) so you might need to do other stuff to coerce bad values then try a different type

Answer (score 0):

You can try change the column data type first.
For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0], columns=['A'])

    A
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  4.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

now

```
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(int)

    A
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  3.0
3  4.0
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

If you have some np.NaN in the column you can try

```
df = df.astype('Int64')
```

This will get you

```
     A
 0  1.0
 1  2.0
 2  3.0
 3  4.0
 4  <NA>
```

Where < NA> is the Int64 equilavent to np.NaN. **Is important to know that np:NaN is a float** and < NA> is not widely used yet and is not memory and performance optimized, you can read more about here
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#integer-dtypes-and-missing-data

Comment: @Allolz and @Evert Acosta -- I tried  `csv_data = pd.read_csv("~/Documents/the_file.csv")` 'csv_data['theColName'] = csv_data['theColName'].astype(int)` but it generated the error as `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`, which I think is due to the reason that there are some missing values -- Also, I don't want to remove these missing values as they are important for me.

Answer (score 0):

`csv_data['theColName'] = csv_data['theColName'].fillna(0)`
`csv_data['theColName'] = csv_data['theColName'].astype('int64')` worked and the column is successfully converted to int64. Thanks everybody